# Using Node.js Custer module on GCP Cloud run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

As per the documentation I am building and deploying my code to Cloud Run. I have configured the machine it's running on the have 2 CPU cores.

Since Cloud Run manages scaling automatically, will I get additional performance benefits from using the Node cluster module to utilize both CPU cores on the host machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code can leverage 2 (or more) CPU in the same time to process the same request, using more than 1 CPU makes sense.

If, as the majority of the developers, you use NodeJS as-is, a single-thread runtime, don't set 2 CPU on your cloud run service. Set one, and let Cloud Run scaling automatically the number of parallel instances.

At high level, it's like having a cluster of VM; or a big multi CPU VM with 1 thread per CPU. It's the power of horizontal scaling by keeping the code simple.

Comment: Thank you @guillaume blaquiere this is exactly the answer I was looking for